# Unable to figure out this google colab error

Tags: tensorflow, syntax, google-colaboratory

I want to use Tensorflow Federated on Google Colab so I pip installed tensorflow_federated but even after this I am getting some error which I am not able to solve .
[image: Description]

I looked up google but could not find any similar errors here on stack overflow.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information, please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/20153035)

Comment: Hi @BipulKumar, I was able to replicate the same in [colab](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/synandi/1573cb8d575faa797e3104fa82fc5c4c/untitled215.ipynb). Kindly try again by installing the nightly version of tensorflow_federated as it is resolved in it. Please refer to this [gist](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/synandi/db3c2fd4d32bf9d178e6bbc828d5d272/untitled214.ipynb). Thank you!

Comment: @Tfer3 Thanks I eventually solved the problem.